# Fastest-updating magazine

Tags: manga-production

Popular manga magazines like Weekly Shōnen Sunday and Weekly Shōnen Magazine update manga weekly. Others like Monthly Shōnen Sunday and Monthly Shōnen Magazine update monthly.

Are there manga magazines or standalone manga that update faster than weekly? If there are, which is the fastest-updating one?

Comment: Given that the mangaka actually script, storyboard, and draw the entire chapter in between magazine issues, that would be quite a trick to publish more than weekly, but it might be possible with individual yon-koma strips, more like US newspaper comics.

Comment: Is the question limited only to printed magazine or also including paperless (e.g. electronic/online) magazine? Also, the title mention "magazine" but the question included "standalone manga", could you clarify by "standalone manga"?

Comment: By standalone, I mean manga that is not published in a magazine. Also, the manga in question _isn't_ limited to print.